# Unable to modify Request Body in Middleware for Entity Creation strapi v4

Tags: node.js, backend, strapi, koa

I've set up a middleware for the `/api/deposits` route to check if the user is authenticated. If authenticated, I want to modify the `users_permissions_user` field in the request body before the entity creation process.

I have tried the following:

Here's a simplified version of my middleware:

1. **ctx.request.body.users_permissions_user = 7;**
2. **ctx.request.body = { ...ctx.request.body, users_permissions_user: 7 }**
3. **ctx.set('users_permissions_user', 7)**

```js
module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
  // Check if user is authenticated
  if (ctx.state.user) {
    // Attempting to modify the request body to set users_permissions_user
    // Attempt 1
    // ctx.request.body.users_permissions_user = 7;

    // Attempt 2
    // ctx.request = { ...ctx.request.body, users_permissions_user: 7 };

    // Attempt 3
    // ctx.set('users_permissions_user', 7);
  }

  // Continue with the next middleware or the entity creation process
  await next();
};
```

However, none of my attempts to modify the `users_permissions_user` field in the request body seem to work. The field remains unset after the request is processed.

Is there a recommended way to modify the request body in a middleware for entity creation? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77604230/strapi-how-to-generate-ordernumber-automatically-in-strapi/77617937#77617937