# Strapi : How to generate ordernumber automatically in strapi

Tags: database, strapi

Using Strapi : 4.15.5

How can we develop a process for orderno to be generated automatically(like ord103) in strapi

eg : need a order number as ord101,ord102,ord103.this should created automatically in orderno field in strapi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom content type to keep a record of a sequential order number.

This the tricky part -
Then access the "sequence order number) in a route middleware/policy to increment and assign it to your content body under a lifecycle for example. Your life cycle could look something like this.

Use a policy to assign the order number to your body -

Under your "src/api/<content_type_name>/policies/<my_policy_name>.js"

```
module.exports = (ctx, config, { strapi }) => {
    
    const {id : userId} = ctx.state.user;
  
    // Add your own logic here.
    strapi.log.info(`In customer policy... ${userId}`);

    const canDoSomething = true;

    if (ctx.state.user.role.name === 'Customer') {

      ctx.request.body.data.orderNo = <MY_NEWLY_GENERATED_ORDER_ID>

      return true
    } else {

      throw new PolicyError('You are not allowed to perform this action', {
        policy: 'customer-policy',
        myCustomKey: 'myCustomValue',
      });

    }

};
```

Under your "src/api/<content_type_name>/content-types/<content_type_name>/lifecycles.js"

```
module.exports = {
    // before creating customer order
    beforeCreate(event) {
      const { data, where, select, populate } = event.params;       
      event.params.data.orderNo  = 'ord' + data.orderNo;
    },
  
    afterCreate(event) {
      const { result, params } = event;
  
      // do something to the result;
    },

};
```